# cannot ssh to server as I install poste.io on OVH dedicated server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker, mail-server, dedicated-server

I want to install poste.io with docker on my server . Poste.io & Docker installed without problem and running fine but when my connection dropped and I try ssh to server again, my connection will be timed out and cannot connect to server.

The docker command:

```
docker run \ -p 25:25 \ -p 9925:80 \ -p 110:110 \ -p 143:143 \ -p 9926:443 \ -p 465:465 \ -p 587:587 \ -p 993:993 \ -p 995:995 \ -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \ -v /root/mailserver/data:/data \ --name "mailserver" \ -t analogic/poste.io
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a port translation option for port 22 on your container. Add a '-p 22:22' right before the '-p 25:25'.

Comment: I don't want ssh to docker container, I want to ssh to main host that docker is running on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem but not completely.
As I changed ssh server port to another(not 22) , I can connect to server via ssh.
(I don't know why docker run on server ssh on port 22 not worked.)